# Распаковка архивов из подкаталогов рядом с архивами

Tags: windows, powershell, файловая-система, архивация, totalcommander

Есть структура папок:

```
Папка 1
  Папка 1-1
    Папка 1-1-1
      Архив 1.zip
      Док.txt
    Папка 1-1-2
      Архив 2.zip
      Изображение.jpg
    Папка 1-1-3
      Архив 3.zip
  Папка 1-2
    Папка 1-2-1
      Архив F.zip
Папка 2
  Папка 2-1
    Папка 2-1-1
      Архив Ф.zip
```

Получаю список файлов подкаталогах **Ctrl+B**, сортирую по расширению...
И дальше тупик:
**7z** не распаковывает каждый архив рядом с архивом
**TC** по **Alt+F9** (распаковка) все кладет в одну директорию

Как распаковать архивы средствами **TC** рядом с архивами во всех подкаталогах?
Это вообще можно сделать, или проще скрипт **PS** написать?

Comment: Если вопрос по TC или иным программам -- вам на https://superuser.com/ (вопрос не по теме этого сайта: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); Если вопрос по powershell, то продемонстрируйте, чего уже добились, что не получается.

Comment: Вопрос по ТС... Спасибо за ссылку, но у меня с английским не очень, что бы там вопрос задать...

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай, держите вариант на PowerShell (только для zip):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Папка 1' -Recurse -Include '*.zip' | ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($_.FullName, $_.Directory.FullName)
}
```